# Can I use the same nonce for multiple requests on the same page?

Tags: php, ajax, nonce

Or does this break the purpose of the nonce, which I admint I don't quite understand it? :)

For example on two ajax requests that run on page load, or when something is clicked:

```
 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'admin-ajax.php',
   data: { action: 'foo',
           _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo $nonce; ?>' }
 });

 $.ajax({
   type: 'post',
   url: 'admin-ajax.php',
   data: { action: 'foo2',
           _ajax_nonce: '<?php echo $nonce; ?>' }
 });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [WordPress nonce creation function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_create_nonce) is to be called only on the [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) hook:

> Use the init or any subsequent action to call this function. Calling
>   it outside of an action can lead to troubles. See [#14024](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14024) for details.

Since the `init` hook "runs after WordPress has finished loading but before any headers are sent", nonces are created on every full-page request (not ajax request). 
So, technically, you can use  the same nonce on multiple requests, but **you should make them unique on each request**, as other answers have pointed out.

---

To shed some more light about what nonces are:

**[Nonces](http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/improving-security-in-wordpress-plugins-using-nonces) are sent on each Ajax request as a security token,** to ensure the request was intended by the user.

Comment: That conclusion seems to be based on the incorrect assumption that nonces are a way to prevent identity theft. See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/32361/205

Comment: @scribu thanks for the insight. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, nonces are highly confusing. :)

While the concept of nonce implies that it is only used once, WordPress does not enforce that and technically you can use nonce multiple times.

However since nonce is used to verify intent (as in did you really mean to perform specific action) - different actions should have different nonces generated and checked.